# Unable to login to an AAD enterprise app using MS creds in edge browser

Tags: google-chrome, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, microsoft-edge, azure-app-registration

User is unable to login into AAD Enterprise app using her MS creds. This issue is limited to single user and on single machine (AAD registered). However, in chrome window, user is able to login to the same app. When login via edge window user is getting below error

**Request Id: 879ab28b-cc74-4594-99d0-XXXXXXXXXX
Correlation Id: f60e1fb0-2d41-44f4-a8cd-XXXXXXXXX
Timestamp: 2023-09-22T17:47:14Z
Message: AADSTS75011: Authentication method 'X509, WindowsIntegrated' by which the user authenticated with the service doesn't match requested authentication method 'Password, ProtectedTransport'. Contact the XXXX application owner.**

I ran the AAD diagnostic logs and found below soln.

**Based on the information you provided we have identified following issue and recommend taking the action to resolve the issue.
Error Code: 75011
Message: Authentication method '' by which the user authenticated with the service doesn't match requested authentication method ''. Contact the application owner.
Action: The user has used an authentication method different from the one requested by the application in the RequestedAuthnContext element in the request. To resolve the problem check with the application developer if they can omit the RequestedAuthnContext element in the request. This usually requires consulting application documentation or contacting the app side administrators. Resolving this problem may require consulting application documentation, checking the application service side configuration or contacting application administrators for help.**

Strange thing is that the failed login is showed only in edge window and for single user and on single machine. the same user when using different machine, she is able to login even with edge browser.
I checked and compared the Device info from good sign in and failed sign in and I found that in bad sign in below info was there in logs

**Device ID
25253f6c-cede-xxxxxx-b36b0edd898c
Browser Edge 117.0.2045
Operating System    Windows10
Compliant   No
Managed No
Join Type   Azure AD registered**

And when I check the good sign in device info I found below info for same user when trying using chrome window to access same app

**Device ID

Browser Chrome 117.0.0
Operating System    Windows10
Compliant   No
Managed No
Join Type**

I am confused on this strange behavior of AAD. Why it authenticates the user successfully when she is using chrome window and not in edge window. Need help on this case.